# Prevent cyclical replication in Kafka MirrorMaker2 while `replication.policy.class = org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy` is set

Tags: apache-kafka, disaster-recovery, apache-kafka-mirrormaker, geo-replication

I am currently trying to create a setup using Kafka MirrorMaker 2 that resembles the MirrorMaker 1 setup we are currently using. Our apps are not configured to be able to consume from multiple topic queues, so replicating to a topic with a tagged name is not currently an option. Our configuration uses an Active-Passive setup where only a singular Kafka cluster is ever being consumed from.
We have 2 sites, for the purpose of explanation I'l call them siteA and siteB. siteA is normally active (primary) while siteB is normally passive (DR). Each site has a kafka cluster as well as a kafka mirrormaker 2 node that is configured to only produce to the kafka cluster in it's own site. To prevent cyclical replication, only one direction of replication is ever set to true. I have managed to get the topics to replicate between the two clusters without renaming using the following config `replication.policy.class = org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy`
However, whenever I flip the replication (stopping replication from siteA to siteB and turning on replication from siteB to siteA), the Mirrormaker 2 instance replicates the messages back to siteA that siteA had previously replicated to siteB. Is there a way to make this work without duplicating the messages or is replicating to a tagged topic the only way forward?

I've tried increasing the frequency of `emit.checkpoints.interval.seconds`, manually turning on `group.offsets.enabled` for the relative clusters, and increasing the frequency of `sync.group.offsets.interval.seconds`. Regardless of these changes, the nessages seem to still be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I have already been in your shoes and probably I will disappoint you but this is not possible using the policy in question. The mention policy is used only for active/passive DR scenarios.

If you still want to achieve this behavior then you have two options:

a) Using default replication policy and set prefix for each existing topic like - siteA.topic1/siteB.topic1

b) Recreate the cluster from siteA when you would like to go back to region A and want to replicate everything back from siteB -> siteA.
It is because of the nature of MirrorMaker no matter the version of it.

I hope this helps !